# fix error tiva tm4c1233gh6pm interfacing with esp01 wifi module with uart0 and uart2

Tags: c, microcontroller

help me, UART0 is defined as simple uart function, UART0 is connected to putty with usb cable uart tx is connected with rx of wifi module and tx with rx of wifi module iam trying to send AT command to esp01 with uart2 and receive with uart2 and transmit it to putty with uarttx(uarttx)

`

```
`#include <TM4C123.h>
void SystemInit(void){
};
/******************************************************************************
* Macros for System Control Block Register Addresses
*******************************************************************************/
#define SYSCTL_RCGC_UART_R      (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400FE618))
#define SYSCTL_RCGC_GPIO_R      (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400FE608)) 

#define GPIO_PORTA_AFSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40004420))
#define GPIO_PORTA_PCTL_R       (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000452C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DEN_R        (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000451C))
#define GPIO_PORTA_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40004400))

#define GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400073FC))
#define GPIO_PORTD_DIR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007400))
#define GPIO_PORTD_IS_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007404))
#define GPIO_PORTD_IBE_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007408))
#define GPIO_PORTD_IEV_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000740C))
#define GPIO_PORTD_IM_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007410))
#define GPIO_PORTD_RIS_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007414))
#define GPIO_PORTD_MIS_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007418))
#define GPIO_PORTD_ICR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000741C))
#define GPIO_PORTD_AFSEL_R          (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007420))
#define GPIO_PORTD_PUR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007510))
#define GPIO_PORTD_PDR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007514))
#define GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000751C))
#define GPIO_PORTD_LOCK_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007520))
#define GPIO_PORTD_CR_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40007524))
#define GPIO_PORTD_PCTL_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000752C))

#define UART0_CTL_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C030))
#define UART0_IBRD_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C024))
#define UART0_FBRD_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C028))
#define UART0_LCRH_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C02C))
#define UART0_CC_R              (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000CFC8))
#define UART0_FR_R              (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C018))
#define UART0_DR_R              (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000C000))

#define UART2_DR_R                  (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E000))
#define UART2_FR_R                  (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E018))
#define UART2_IBRD_R                (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E024))
#define UART2_FBRD_R                (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E028))
#define UART2_LCRH_R                (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E02C))
#define UART2_CTL_R                 (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E030))
#define UART2_CC_R                  (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000EFC8))
#define UART2_IFLS_R                (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E034))
#define UART2_IM_R                  (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E038))
#define UART2_MIS_R                 (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E03C))
#define UART2_RIS_R                 (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E040))
#define UART2_ICR_R                 (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000E044))

#define GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400053FC))
#define GPIO_PORTB_DIR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005400))
#define GPIO_PORTB_IS_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005404))
#define GPIO_PORTB_IBE_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005408))
#define GPIO_PORTB_IEV_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000540C))
#define GPIO_PORTB_IM_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005410))
#define GPIO_PORTB_RIS_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005414))
#define GPIO_PORTB_MIS_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005418))
#define GPIO_PORTB_ICR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000541C))
#define GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL_R          (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005420))
#define GPIO_PORTB_PUR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005510))
#define GPIO_PORTB_PDR_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005514))
#define GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R            (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000551C))
#define GPIO_PORTB_LOCK_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005520))
#define GPIO_PORTB_CR_R             (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x40005524))
#define GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R           (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x4000552C))

#define UART_FR_TX_FF           0x20                        
#define UART_FR_RX_FE           0x10  

unsigned char UARTRx(void);
unsigned char UART2Rx(void);
void UARTTx(unsigned char data);
void UART2Tx(unsigned char data);
void UARTTxString(char* pt);
void UART2TxString(char* pt);
void UARTRxString(char* bufPt, unsigned short max);
void UART2RxString(void);
void ESP01Init(void);
void Delay(unsigned long counter);
// Wait for input and returns its ASCII value
unsigned char UARTRx(void)
{
    while ((UART0_FR_R & UART_FR_RX_FE) != 0);
    return ((unsigned char)(UART0_DR_R & 0x0FF));
}

unsigned char UART2Rx(void)
{
    while ((UART2_FR_R & UART_FR_RX_FE) != 0);
    return ((unsigned char)(UART2_DR_R & 0x0FF));
}


void UART2RxString()
{
    char receivedChar[1000];
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 999)
    {
        char currentChar = UART2Rx();

        // Check for carriage return or line feed as termination characters
        if (currentChar == '\r' || currentChar == '\n')
        {
            // Terminate the string and break out of the loop
            receivedChar[count] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        receivedChar[count] = currentChar;
        count++;
    }

    // Transmit the received string
    UARTTxString(receivedChar);
}







    void Delay(unsigned long counter)
{
  unsigned long i = 0;
  for (i =0; i < counter ; i ++);
}
    // Output 8bit to serial port
void UARTTx(unsigned char data)
{
    while ((UART0_FR_R & UART_FR_TX_FF) != 0);
    UART0_DR_R = data;
}

void UART2Tx(unsigned char data)
{
    while ((UART2_FR_R & UART_FR_TX_FF) != 0);
    UART2_DR_R = data;
}


void UARTTxString(char* pt)
{
    while (*pt)
    {
        UARTTx(*pt); 
        pt++;
    }
}
void UART2TxString(char* pt)
{
    while (*pt)
    {
        UART2Tx(*pt); 
        pt++;
    }
}


void ESP01Init(void)
{
  
    SYSCTL_RCGC_UART_R |= 0x5;
      SYSCTL_RCGC_GPIO_R |= 0xB;
    
    GPIO_PORTA_AFSEL_R |= 0x3;
    GPIO_PORTA_PCTL_R |= 0x11;
    GPIO_PORTA_DEN_R |= 0x3;
    
      GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R |= 0x10;
    GPIO_PORTB_DIR_R |= 0x10;
    GPIO_PORTB_DATA_R   |=0x10;
    
      GPIO_PORTD_LOCK_R = 0x4C4F434B ;
    GPIO_PORTD_CR_R |= 0x00000080 ;
    GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R |= 0x0C0 ; 
       
      GPIO_PORTD_AFSEL_R |= 0x000000C0 ;
    GPIO_PORTD_PCTL_R |= 0x11000000 ;

      UART0_CTL_R |= 0x0;
      UART2_CTL_R |= 0x0;
         
      UART0_CC_R |= 0x05;
      UART2_CC_R |= 0x05;
         
  UART0_IBRD_R  = 8;
    UART0_FBRD_R  = 44;
    UART2_IBRD_R  = 8;
    UART2_FBRD_R  = 44;
        
    UART0_LCRH_R  |= 0x70;
    UART0_LCRH_R  &= ~(0x8);
    UART2_LCRH_R  |= 0x70;
    UART2_LCRH_R  &= ~(0x8);

    UART0_CTL_R |= 0x301;
    UART2_CTL_R |= 0x301;
    
    Delay(100000);
}

int main(void)
{   
    ESP01Init();
     UART2TxString("AT\r\n");
   UART2RxString();
}
   
`
```

i tried many times to change the code but the characters are not received and tranmitted to uart0

Comment: the " the code is enclosed in is not in the actual code formatting error

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time if you want to add more information or correct an error.

Comment: It's not clear which part doesn't work. Can you explain? Your `UART2RxString()` function won't transmit anything until it has received 1000 characters. Is that intentional?

Comment: yeah well it does not really matter its just an upper limit it will break out of the loop when \n or \r is received

Comment: i asked a peer of mine he said to send AT command as AT\r\n then it will send the command and tell that tranmission is ended

Comment: @pmacfarlane can you check the code?